# After install eclim cant find $ECLIPSE_HOME/eclimd file

Tags: eclim

I try install eclim using Graphical Installer by http://eclim.org/install.html tutorial. Installation process complited without errors, but eclim not working. Not found $ $ECLIPSE_HOME/eclimd file on my eclipse root directory, but $HOME/.vim was created succesful.

Where I should look for eclimd?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this thread with no solution trying to figure out the same thing.

I was able to find the launcher under:
"~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.7.0_155965261_linux_gtk_x86_64/"

Answer (score -1):

I was just looking for a solution as I was facing the same problem to choose eclipse installation directory otherwise I was unable to proceed eclim installation. However I tried to choose different directories and finally I found the right installation directory

"/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse"

That worked for me I hope this will help you as well.